# Can't compile after upgrading from 1.10.. to 1.11

Tags: build-bpf

I upgraded my solana tools and running `cargo build-sbf`, `cargo-build-sbf` or `cargo build-bpf` results in the following error (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
example-helloworld/src/program-rust$ cargo build-sbf
error: no such subcommand: `+sbf`

        Did you mean `b`?
```

The path in the env  is set properly as:

```
PATH=/home/user/Apps/flutter/bin:/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin
```

Why dosent compiling work. The solana version is `solana-cli 1.11.10 (src:843e018c; feat:4253057308)`

After switching to mainnet beta I get the same error but with `build-bpf`

```
BPF SDK: /home/user/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-dac50a64e8828e8ef459dc7dd9cf54356825d0ec/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: no such subcommand: `+bpf`

        Did you mean `b`?
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, it worked when I used `cargo-build-sbf` instead of `cargo build-sbf` after upgrading all solana tools and cargo.